# Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Previously I worked on jdk 1.7 but today I updated my SDK and I installed api 24(N) but it's showing this error:

> **Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later**.

So I also updated my JDK 1.7 to 1.8. I also changed JDK path in Android studio but it's giving me the same error.

[image: Here screenshot of my project structure]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later. I also restart my studio. I all is wain.

Comment: Do you have installed 1.7 and 1.8 both?

Comment: yes 1.7 and 1.8 are installed.

Comment: then please uninstall java 1.7 and then try again

Comment: try this to set the default java used. `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem after I updated Android studio and all his coumponent.
To fix that I just gone to Setting (Ctrl + Alt + S), then into Android SDK, then removed the versioin from the supprorted.
If you don't look especially for the N previw, it will help.
Hope I helped.